# Is a partial delete of column values in SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to batch edit a column of values in a database. Right now I have a "location" field formatted for Row Bay Level as follows: R001B002L004

Since there are less than ten Rows, Bays or Levels the R00 B00 and L00 are completely redundant and the field would be easier to manage if it were formatted as a three digit number. eg 124 for the previous example.

Is there way I can batch edit these 800 or so values to convert the R00*B00*L00* format to the three digit number format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
update t
    set location = replace(replace(replace(location, 'R00', ''), 'B00', ''), 'L00', '');
```

If you want to turn this into a number, then you have a bit of a challenge.  The current type of location is some sort of string and changing the type is probably a lot of unnecessary work.  I would just go with a digit-only string.